# List of lists - Compare neighboring values and IF second elements are the same - take older one

Tags: python, compare

I'm trying to find a more elegant solution to this task: we have a list of lists with date and value pairs -> need to compare to neighbor value and IF values are the same - we pick up only the oldest date (BUT it should work only for close neighbors).

```
l = [[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0],
    [datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0), 0],  # need to skipp
    [datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0), 2],
    [datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0), 0],  # keep!
    [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0), 5]]
```

Expected result:

```
[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Please see an example and how I have solved it so far. Any idea on how to optimize it is much appreciated!

```
def get_dates_1():  # solution 1 with reverse
    l = [[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0), 0],   # need to skip
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0), 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0), 5],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0), 5]]  # need to skip

    l.reverse()
    dates = []

    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i < len(l) - 1:
            if l[i][1] != l[i + 1][1]:
                dates.append(l[i][0])
        else:
            dates.append(l[i][0])
    return list(reversed(dates))

def get_dates_2():   # solution 2 w/o reverse
    l = [[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0), 0],   # need to skip
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0), 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0), 5],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0), 5]]  # need to skip

    l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    result = [l[0]]
    for date, value in l:
        if value != result[-1][1]:
            result.append([date, value])

    dates = [x for x, _ in result]
    return dates
```

Expected:

```
[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Can you have more than 2 adjacent elements with the same value, or are they always just pairs?

Comment: `itertools.groupby()` would be useful for this.

Comment: Hi @Barman! Done :) On the l structure - it is always expected to be in pairs [date, int].

Comment: No, I mean can you have more than 2 adjacent elements with the same `int` value?

Comment: ahh, yes it's possible     l = [[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0), 0],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0), 0],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0), 0],
         [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0), 5]]  -> expect to have 1st and last date from here

Comment: Then your code is wong. If there are N adjacent rows, it will put N-1 of them into the result. Use `groupby()` to merge them all.

Comment: Hm.. I've just tested and both functions gave [datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0)] - same as I expected given the l structure as from the previous comment. As for the groupby - can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution uses `itertools.groupyby` to break the list into sub-groups.

```py
import datetime
import itertools


def get_dates():

    my_list = [
        [datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0), 0],
        [datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0],

        [datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0), 2],

        [datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0), 5],
        [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0), 5]
    ]

    result = [
        # Within each group, sort, and pick out the first (oldest) list
        sorted(group)[0][0]

        # Group the sub-lists by the second element
        for _, group in itertools.groupby(my_list, key=lambda li: li[1])
    ]

    return result


for x in get_dates():
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0]
[datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0), 2]
[datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0), 5]
```

Comment: Good option! Thank you @Hai Vu!